# vector data check

Tags: vector, copy

hi a have a function that reads from a text file line by line each line I do some operations on it substitute a string..etc

then I push_back that line into a vector

this is my class in Parser.h

```
class Parser
{// start class
public:
vector<const char*> patterns;

Parser();
~Parser(); 
void RuleParser(const char *TextFileName); // this is the function that takes the file name

private:
};// end class
```

segment from function RuleParser

```
 std::ifstream ifs(TextFileName);
 while (!ifs.eof()) 
 {
 .
 .modification code
 .
 patterns.push_back((buildString).c_str()); //buildString is the modified line
 cout << buildString << endl;
 }
```

but when I try to check out if the data in the vector is correct it output totally different data.
I even put a cout after the push_back to check it's integrty but I found buildString is correct... thats the data each time being pushed ... what I am doing wrong.

here is the loop I use to see if my data correct.

```
for (int i = 0;i < patterns.size() ;i++)
{
cout << patterns.at(i) << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well patterns is the collection of pointers so you end up push_back'ing a pointer to the same buildString in each iteration of the loop, instead of push_back'ing the string contents. Then when buildString changes in next iteration of the loop, the pointer becomes invalid but it still remains in patterns - not good

I suggest you declare patterns as:

```
vector<std::string> patterns;
```

This way when you do:

```
patterns.push_back(buildString.c_str())
```

the contents of the string will be copied instead of the pointer, and remain valid througout.

Comment: patterns.push_back(strdup(buf.c_str()));